# How to access Bash's charbuffer

Tags: linux, bash, console

Is there any reasonable way to take control of bash's `charbuffer`?

Something similar to Windows's `SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer`.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
https://youtu.be/xW8skO7MFYw?t=2255
```

In case you know other way, I'm trying to use the console `charbuffer` as a framebuffer for graphics.

Comment: Position cursor at x=20, y=10 and print one `#`: `printf "%b" "\033[10;20H#"`

Answer (score 0):

ncurses is what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @Helper, this answer appears to be more appropriate as a comment, unless you wish to elaborate with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You will need to write a few more answers before you can write comments like the one you have done here.